# Ignoring viewDidAppear when dismissing a modal view via a delegate

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a delegate on my modal view controller which activates the following on my parent view

```
- (void)userTappedOnBackButton
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This successfully dismisses the view.

On the main view's didAppear, data is loaded and a table is bound.

How can I inform the view not to reload this data if the view is displayed via this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag in the parent view controller like `self.hasModalOnTop = YES` before presenting modal view controller. And check this value in viewDidAppear like this.

```
if(!self.hasModalOnTop) {
    // load data and bind table
}
self.hasModalOnTop = NO;
```

A little bit hacky, but should work.